# pass two argument and fetch them using php $_GET[] code

Tags: php, arguments

on the first page:-

```
<?php
$post_id=123467890;
$post_status="publish";
?>

<a href="temp_views/post_view.php?postid=<?php echo $post_id;?>&status=<?php echo $post_status;?>" target="_blank" style="color: darkgreen;"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a>
```

on the second page:-

```
echo $_post_status=isset($_GET['post_id']); // this give me 123467890 that is 
                                           //correct
echo $_post_status=isset($_GET['status']); // this giving me 1 why?
```

Comment: In PHP 7+ you can use `$_post_status=$_GET['post_id']??"";` (Null coalescing operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset()` always give true or false. `isset()` is used to check whether value is set to variable or not.  if you want to get value then you have to add your $_GET['status'] in if condition like example.

```
if(isset($_GET['status'])) { 
       $_post_status= $_GET['status'] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`isset()` function returns `TRUE` if var exists and has value other than `NULL`. `FALSE` otherwise.

Try this this

```
echo $_post_id = isset($_GET['post_id'])?$_GET['post_id']:""; // this give me 123467890 that is 
                                           //correct
echo $_post_status = isset($_GET['status'])?$_GET['status']:""; // this giving me 1 why?
```

read about [iseet()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)